# WP7 (windows phone 7) HttpWebRequest losing POST data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, post, httpwebrequest

I'm sending a lot of POST data (over 5000 chars) and it seems that WP7 HttpWebRequest is losing some of the content in the process...

The data is a png converted to a byte array and after to a base64 string.

If my data is 4941 characters long, it will send only 1448 chars, the content length (verified with wireshark) of the request is fine (Content-Length: 4991).

How i send the data :

```
void SendPost()
{
    // Create the web request object
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Start the request
    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);

}

void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    // End the stream request operation
    Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

    // Create the post data
    // Demo POST data (length = 3762)
    string postData = "data=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";

    //Actual code used
    /*for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Count; i++)
    {
        // Parameter seperator
        if (i > 0)
        {
            postData += "&";
        }

         // Parameter data
         postData += paramNames[i] + "=" + paramValues[i];
    }*/

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    // Add the post data to the web request
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    // Start the web request
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
}

void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response;

        // End the get response operation
        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();

    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
            // Error treatment
            // ...
    }
}
```

How can I send my data entirely ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are any errors being returned, or a redirect occurring at some point?

Comment: No errors are returned, just the server response saying it can't analyse the image. What do you mean by redirect ? proxy redirecting the request ?

Comment: Do you have visibility to what is happening on the server?  Is it possible the server is not reading the whole content, but is instead reading the first "chunk", and needs to make further read calls to read the complete content?

Comment: I have visiblity on the server, but it's on the emulator side. Because I use wireshark on my computer and the request is sended with some data missing.

Comment: You are not disposing of the postStream, although closing it should do the trick - you might try wrapping it in a "using" or doing postStream.Dispose().  Totally irrelevent to the question, but you should think about using a StringBuilder to build up the string, since it will result in much fewer objects being created ...  Could you put a try/catch in the method to make sure nothing is going wrong inside the method?

Comment: I added .dispose() after the .Close() and a try catch. No exception caught and always an incomplete request...

Comment: In Wireshark - check the sent content itself. If it is passed in its entirety, your service is doing something wrong with the received content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In RunSat I send plenty more bytes than that using the code below - its similar to the code you've shown and it works fine (although I admit I mainly test on a real device)

```
            Stream requestStream = CurrentWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(async);
            byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            requestStream.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Flush();
            requestStream.Close();
```

---

Depending on how expert you are with WireShark, it might not be telling you the whole truth - when you're looking at wireshark you will see the TCP level packets which (for ip4) commonly have 1448 bytes of payload - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_segmentation_offload - and I find it easy to miss the continuation packets. (I'm not a wireshark user, but have used ethereal a bit)

---

Update: I've run this code below

It works fine - you can see the upload at http://posttestserver.com/data/2011/05/12/03.29.331923823079

I recommend you stop messing about at the ethernet and TCP/IP packet levels with WireShark and take a look at your webservice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace DemoProject
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SendPost();
        }

        void SendPost()
        {
            var url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php";

            // Create the web request object
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Start the request
            webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);    
        }

        void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

            // Create the post data
            // Demo POST data 
            string postData = "data=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";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Add the post data to the web request
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the web request
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
        }

        void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {    
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;

                // End the get response operation
                response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();

            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                // Error treatment
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stuart I assume that "Follow TCP stream" would put together all the packets of the request. Is there a special way to do it ? Do you have to add some parameters to the request to handle large data ? I'm using HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Comment: Maybe try using Fiddler instead of wireshark - wireshark is at the TCP/Network adapter level - too fiddly.

Comment: +1 Good catch recognising the 1448 bytes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_segment_offload

Comment: Actually, it's sending the data in 2 packets : one with the header (len : 341) and an other with the begining of the content (len : 1460). I'm still missing something like 2000 chars...

Comment: What does Fiddler show you? Does it show you the truncated message?

Comment: Also... what happens if you just try sending a test block of 5000 bytes of numeric (0,1,2,...) data - or can you post more of your code - currently I see no major differences between the working runsat code and what you've posted

Comment: Fiddler isn't working with the office's proxy... What part(s) of my code can be usefull ?

Comment: If you could produce one 10 line code block that demos the problem that would be good - e.g. something that creates a block of 5000 bytes of data, creates a web request, and fills the request stream. just standalone code - no dependencies on paramNames or anything else.

Comment: I 've posted the begining of my code (function sendPost()). I'll post a standalone code, but you'll still need a web service to receive the datas.

Comment: I've updated my answer - looks to me like the problem is not in the phone code or in the emulator.

Comment: After testing with http://posttestserver.com/ (wich I just discovered, thanks to you), with the phone UNTETHERED and on 3G network. It works just fine... The error comme from the proxy or the server. You CAN send without problem large amount of data. Thanks again for your help and for that usefull website.