# What is the easiest way to POST using WebRequest for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have a URL `http://www.test.com/` and I want to send `&q=1&t=2` as the POST request.

Also, I need to be able to read the return value as a `string`.

What is the simplest code to do a task like this?

Comment: Please check this post . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952094/wp7-windows-phone-7-httpwebrequest-losing-post-data

Answer (score 0):

This [**post**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8/) on Social MSDN explains the difference between WebClient and HttpWebRequest. The code for both uses is show a bit down. The main difference directly visible is that WebClient runs on the UI thread and no Dispatcher is required to update the UI. This *is* the case when using HttpWebRequest as it runs on a different thread. If you have small amount of data, using the WebClient will be sufficient. Hope this helps!